# Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7056; process output follows: null

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am using FireFox 18 with Selenium 2.29.0.
While running test exception occurs

Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7056; process output follows: null

It seems strange that this error seldom occurs. Let's say I have 20 tests in my class, the "failed to connect" error occurs in 2 tests sometimes 3 and sometimes it doesn't occur.

Can't figure out why is it happening. If this is some how version problem or something else, none of the test case should run.

Comment: 1st - try upgrading selenium to 2.31.0 - always, always, ALWAYS do use the latest release...

Comment: It is really important in Selenium that you find a Selenium version and a Browser version that are compatible. Especially with Firefox the support only is in beta stage. If you found such a combination it is best to first stick to exactly that combination. If you update the browser without Selenium it will probably break, same for vice versa. *"Never change a running system"* really applies here. If you plan to update you need to find a stable combination of Selenium and Browser again. Of course updating is important for brand new websites.

Comment: It also really depends on what webpages you are visiting. They may have fancy features that break Selenium. If the page is very simple it probably doesn't crash often.

Answer (score 0):

If you have path variable at your environment variables not set..then set it to location of Firefox.exe....
Or you can explicitly mention  path to firefox.exe a

```
File pathToFirefoxBinary = new File(browser);
FirefoxBinary firefoxbin = new FirefoxBinary(pathToFirefoxBinary);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxbin,null);
```

This should work..
Or u can go for upgradation to 2.31.0

Comment: @Pavel But why it doesn't give the error every time, some time it gives error and sometime it doesn't ? If selenium doesn't find the path , it should n't run a single time.

Comment: @TahaIqbal I am getting the same error sporadically, were you able to find a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem when i was using firefox 28.0, I solved it by downgrading Firefox version to 27.0.1